# How to enable modules through configuration?

Tags: 8, installation, configuration, installation-profiles

I am trying to enable modules by adding them to `core.extension.yml` file without getting involved with Features, Configuration Installer or similar modules or profiles. The modules are enabled but their default configuration under `module_folder/config/install` or `module_folder/config/optional` are not imported. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So when exactly do you want to install a module? Installing a module through core.extension is perfectly valid *if* you're doing it as part of an config import. But then you have to provide all the configuration of the module also in the config sync folder. Usually you install the module somewhere on a test site, optionally customize the configuration, then export that, deploy it and import. You don't need features or anything like that. And you only need Config Installer if you try to install a completely new site through tat

Comment: @Berdir thank you man, I was thinking that there is no one around here anymore after a few unanswered questions. Faith in Drupal Answers restored:) -- Since the projects I am doing is not that big and I am very lazy, I am not setting up clones for such testing purposes. But yes that's an ideal workflow. As of the Config Installer, I saw some issues in the queue and didn't wanna get involved with the module since it could give me more headache then manually installing 25 modules :)

Comment: How do you solve your problem?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer hi, thanks for the follow up. I haven't tried any of them yet. I'll try in my next project and select an answer.

Comment: @duru well just publish your solution, I think that this is a good question ;-)

Comment: @duru finally how do you solve the problem?

Comment: Hey Adrian, thanks for the follow-up. I haven't yet. I'll update this as soon as I start a new project with the requirements above. This isn't happening so often, so it'd better wait for better testing. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not works because you are only saying to Drupal that your module is installed, but when you install a module there are other process that need to runs to import the configs and execute the .install functions.

But you can create a new module that will install all the other modules, create a .install file and add this inside:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function MY_MODULE_install() {
  $modules_list = [
    'nbsp',
    'typogrify',
    'other_module',
  ];
  \Drupal::service('module_installer')->install($modules_list);
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

And then you only need to install this module that will install all the other modules.

Comment: @duru a pleasure help you, at the end lets us know which method you chose and why.

Comment: looks like @duru is still thinking about which answer to "chose" (= mark as accepted?) ...

Comment: Mind that `hook_install` will run on module installation only. If your module is already installed, use `hook_update_N` like CG Monroe answer.

Answer (score 4):

A possible alternative would be use the dependencies section of a module's mymod.info.yml description.  Enabling the module will enable the dependencies.

```
name: My Module
description: Provides something great
core: 8.x
type: module
dependencies:
  - views
```

If you need to make sure that certain modules are enabled due to code changes in an existing module, then use update system.  E.g. add a hook_update_N function to  the mymod.install file that calls the module.installer service.

```
/**
 * Install file module.
 */
function mymod_update_8001() {
  \Drupal::service('module_installer')->install(['file']);
}
```

FYI - Trying to install an installed module will not cause problems.

Trying to go outside the normal system by accessing the core.extensions is probably not a long term maintainable option.

Comment: Cool. Let's see if there will be other answers.

Comment: @duru If you install as a dependency then can't uninstall any module because all are needed by your module (the module that install all the other modules), and if you use the hook_update() then you need to install the module and after run the update. This is why I think that is better put the code in the .install file, but it depends from your requirements.